# How to get value of dynamically added input inside ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-model

I am trying to get the value of inputs that are created when a box is clicked. These inputs are inside a ng-repeat. I tried sending item inside ng-click but since it is outside the ng-repeat it would not work. I can't seem to figure out how to get the values each input. 
Any help would be really appreciated!

**HTML**

```
<div class="tagBox" ng-repeat="item in inputs">
    <input ng-model="itemValue"/>
</div>
<span class="btn btn-link topic-link" ng-click="addInput(item)">
     Add Another Topic
</span>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.inputs = []
$scope.addInput = function(){
    $scope.inputs.push({})
}
```

Comment: you called the method passing an argument, but your function isn't accepting any argument, but seems to just be pushing completely empty objects into the array.  also, your `ng-model` doesn't appear to be declared correctly.  You should consider posting a plunker of your issue, unless it is just a series of typos.

Comment: Updating inputs should be enough. I'm pretty sure you just don't see anything because you're adding empty objects...

Comment: Why are you adding item in the ng-click outside the repeat? why are you passing a param when the add input function does not take a param and just pushes an empty object? You also have a single model set for every item in the repeat, this will not work. When you say "I'm trying to get the value" what exactly do you mean here? It's confusing because the code you have here doesn't really make sense :( .

Answer (score 0):

The way it looks right now is that you're binding all of your inputs to $scope.itemValue. The best way to get that information would be to initialize $scope.itemValue as an array and then do something like:

```
<div class="tagBox" ng-repeat="item in inputs">
    <input ng-model="itemValue[$index]">
</div>
```

Then you can get all of your values inside the $scope.itemValue array.